# HTML code reflecting the output after I shrink the screen

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using canvas(graph) in my Angular JS UI5 application, I just want to increase the width of the graph. If I change the size of the Graph its not changing instead, if I shrink the screen it reflecting.

Can anyone please let me know if any idea?

```
<div class='col-sm-12'>
    <div  class='form-group col-sm-6' ng-show ='showBar === "1"'>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: **100**%;">
        </div>
    </div>
<div class='col-sm-12'>
    <div  class='form-group col-sm-6' ng-show ='showBar === "1"'>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: **160**%;">
        </div>
    </div>/
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Bootstrap Grid is limiting and formatting the size of container column.

You can try to overwrite the css position and width of "#chartContainer" ( use [Important](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_color_themes.asp) to force overwrite ), but it may break the Grid structure.

The canvas size will not over it's parent container .

[An explanation of Bootstrap Grid System](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Comment: Same Problem is occuring when increasing the size by ID #chartContainer{
position: absolute !important;
width: 160% !important;
}